# clearcookie doesn't remove httpOnly cookie nodejs

Tags: node.js, cookies, cookie-httponly

My question may be simple but I can't find how to do it and I tried for hours to find a way but I can't.
I have a nodejs back that sets an httpOnly cookie like this

```js
res.cookie('jwt', token, { httpOnly: true, maxAge: 3 * 60 * 60 * 1000 });
```

and I tried both

```js
res.clearCookie('jwt', { httpOnly: true, domain: 'localhost', path: '/' });
```

and

```js
res.cookie('jwt', '', {maxAge:0}); // or just res.cookie('jwt', '') or with httpOnly:true
```

I can't figure out how to remove this cookie please someone help, thanks to anyone who can help.